# What's a robust way to detect user region in a web-app?

Tags: java, javascript, locale, region

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the geoip location for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126959/how-to-find-the-geoip-location-for-all-users)

I never had to face this problem before so I've been doing a bit of reading on this today but surprisingly haven't been able to find anything really helpful on the topic even though one would think this should be a fairly common issue.

**I basically need to detect the user region in a standard web-app and re-direct them to different pages depending on just that.**

What's a standard robust way of doing this and does it require a server component or is there a reasonable client side only solution?

Any examples appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, your three sources of data are:

- the user's IP address against a GeoIP database (which requires a server component),
- the user's browser language setting (which apparently [still requires a server component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)), or
- the user's latitude and longitude from their [smartphone or modern browser](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).

I have heard of geolocation services that will abstract away the need for your own server component, some of which were listed on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283016/know-a-good-ip-address-geolocation-service).