# Detect User's Preferred Language and Google Translate Automatically

Tags: javascript, internationalization, google-translate

I use this script in my site for translation

```
<div id="google_translate_element" align="center"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'auto',
        autoDisplay: false,
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

It is working just fine :)
But is there a way to detect the user ip and auto translate when a user go in to my site?

Comment: Please **read** the tags carefully before applying them to a question.  This has nothing to do with [tag:java].

Comment: *"But is there a way to detect the user ip and auto translate"*  Better to offer a list of language options and let the user choose.  A French national would probably prefer French when traveling in Britain or Germany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can use IP-based location detection (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143618/2016778)), but it's neither reliable nor makes you wiser about user's preferred languages (e.g. users travelling abroad, etc.).

Websites with heavy international traffic use various parameters to decide in which language the content should be presented. Some of these parameters:

- [`Accept-Language`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) HTTP header which is discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3335420/2016778).
- Values of properties `window.navigator.language` or `window.navigator.userLanguage` (for IE)
- IP-based location detection data checked against CLDR to provide you with common languages in that territory.

MediaWiki extension, `UniversalLanguageSelector`, uses these factors as well as stored user preferences to provide a list of common languages for each user. See [`getFrequentLanguageList()`](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/extensions/UniversalLanguageSelector.git;a=blob;f=resources/js/ext.uls.init.js;h=b449c7a5f5c3e236a3688f0c822a0735282039e0;hb=HEAD#l73).

W3C also has some [recommendations](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-when-lang-neg).

Answer (score 2):

This script shows the translation drop-down box only for people with English not set as their primary or only language, and **hides it when English users view the page** - it is coded for English pages using the `en` in the google code.

It uses the first 2 characters of the language only to avoid checking for the [many variants of English](http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.asp) like `en-US`, `en-tt` etc - they all begin with `en`.

This could easily be adapted to detect `pageLanguage` and compare it with the user's preferred language(s). The use of `navigator.languages` is important because this is used on newer browser releases, see [cross-browser compatibility explained](http://gu.illau.me/posts/the-problem-of-user-language-lists-in-javascript/)

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage || navigator.languages; 
if (userLang.substr(0,2) != "en"){
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: 
    google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element');
   }
 }
else { 
  document.getElementById("google_translate_element").style.display="none";
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```