# Google Website Translator Automatic Display Mode

Tags: web, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I'm trying to include google website translator on my website. I want to use the automatic thing so the bar shows up if your browser language is different to the page language. Every time I select the automatic Display mode the code it gives me is for 'tabbed'. Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong or provide the right code?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout:     google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT},     'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Post the code you are using.

Comment: By the way, here is some info on how to ask a question. Congrats on joining us! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the reply @screenmutt. I've edited post with the code.

Comment: Next time make your code a little more readable. But thanks.

Comment: Sorry, that was straight from Google.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you. The Automatic setting isn't sticking. If you look at your settings for the website it'll keep resetting back to tabbed even when you choose Automatic. It should be changing the value of the "layout" option, but it's not clear what the value SHOULD be.

Comment: fix for the automatic setting issue -  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32020889/4258817

Answer (score 2):

I saw another example here:

[Detect User's Preferred Language and Google Translate Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823022/detect-users-preferred-language-and-google-translate-automatically)

This had the parameter  autoDisplay: false,

To get only the translation bar when the site language doesn't match I have deleted the  container, and used autoDisplay: true,

I get the bar when in another language, but no drop down.

Answer (score 2):

While trying to figure out why the autoDisplay was not functioning, i.e. the translate menu always displayed, I found the W3C Internationalization Checker: http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/

The W3C Internationalization Checker alerted me that the Accept Headers were returning:
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

The code generated by Google that I originally pasted into my site files only had one value to check the page language. But I edited it, see below, and passed an array into the pageLanguage key and I think it's now working.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: ['en', 'en-us'], autoDisplay: false, multilanguagePage: true, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-403844-8'}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I ran tests as best I could by changing the language settings in Google Chrome. But I don't fully trust that it's working. The translate menu ought to appear for anyone without en or en-US configured in their browsers. You could pass in any language to the array to properly configure it for your needs.

If anyone has any feedback on this I'd appreciate it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To display the translator only when your page is different from the user's page, have a server side check and only include the code if necessary.

See [Getting Browser Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043339/javascript-for-detecting-browser-language-preference)

Your URL is incorrect. Add "http:". See working example below.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT},
    'google_translate_element');
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still getting the "select language" drop down box. I only want the bar to show up when the browser language is different to the website. I don't really want to go down the display:none route. I'm sure you used to be able to do it very easily...

Comment: In the settings where you generate that code, Google has an option called "Automatic" that only is supposed to display the translation bar at the top of your browser when you are using a different language. When you select that option, it ignores your choice and gives you code to display the dropdown all the time (the "Tabbed" option he refers to in the question). What he's asking is the code for Google's built-in automatic display since their code generator is broken.

Comment: The layout option should have a different value to reflect the "automatic" setting, but it's not totally clear what that would be, and I can't find a site with the code on it to copy it from.

Comment: @RyanGiglio the same problem in 2016, the code generator ignores the "automatic" option. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Funny how Google's code retrieval for the translator automatic function is broken, isn't it? I tried many iterations in the Rincewind level Wizard they have to do the custom setup, but the default was to a Tabbed function that doesn't fit with my website design.

This is for an English site, change the language code for your site default language where the bar isn't supposed to display. Remove the tracking if you're not using it.

```
<!-- <div id="google_translate_element"></div> -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en', 
        autoDisplay: true,
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, 
        gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-xxxxxx-x'
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Basically what the answer by @gm-sb above is getting at, but with full working code so you can have it fully functional in one go.

Comment: this still prompts you to choose a language, even when your language is the same as the page's, see new solution here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32020889/4258817

Comment: Hmm, odd because the above code works on my website without that little oddity. Will keep this in mind if it decides to go rogue on me... Just one of the little things out there that exist to drive my work partner crazy as he gets to fight random weirdness.

Comment: I went through different settings eg autoDisplay and it didn't work, using a stock Android browser it prompted for language every single time even when language was the same as the page's language. Localization (en-US) did not cause the problem but also needed to be solved. I had no issues with the google wizard thing, only with the code it produced. Could it be that I was using Float rather than inline layout?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'id', includedLanguages: 'id', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain something briefly?

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">


function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Other than you need to provide some description

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
          pageLanguage: 'es', 
          includedLanguages: 'es', 
          layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
      }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```