# Automatically Translate Website With Google Translate Plugin (IP & Accept-Language)?

Tags: localization, translation, ip-address, google-translate, http-accept-language

Is there a way to translate my website automatically based on the visitor's IP and "accept-language" header information using Google Translate Plug-in?

Thank you!

Comment: the use of IP is a very bad idea since many countries have multiple official languages, eg Belgium, South Africa.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823022/detect-users-preferred-language-and-google-translate-automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old question, and it is not recommended at all to do this (since a user could just use a vpn) but I was bored so here is what I came up with:

**Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script></head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <center>
        <br/>
        <div id="google_translate_element"></div><br/>
        Country:&nbsp;<span id="country"></span>
        <h1>Hello my friends this is a cool code.</h1>
    </center>
    <script>
    function hc(dc){
        lang = Cookies.get('language');
        if(lang != dc){
            window.location.hash = 'googtrans(en|' + dc + ')';
            location.reload();
            Cookies.set('language', dc);
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp/",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function( location ) {
            $('#country').html(location.country_code);
            co = location.country_code;
            co = co.toLowerCase();
            hc(co); // Replace here
        }
    });
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
    </script>
    <script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explination**:

Basically it sends an Ajax request to https://geolocation-db.com/ (free) and using the json response, it takes out the country code and then replaces the hash to the country code and google translate then translates it. Now this might not be the best way, and there are definitely problems to this, but it works (sometimes ).

**Problems**:

- VPN
- Some countries such as US won't work as "us" is not a language code so you will have to change that.
- Probably other problems

**Try It Out**:

Copy the code and try it out. If you are in the US or some other country that doesn't have it's own language code, to test it just replace the `hc(co);` with your own testing language like `hc('ru');`.

**Requirements**:

- jQuery
- JS-Cookie (Not needed, you can make your own code without this plugin)
- Google Translate API (No Duh)

Comment: Kinda funny this question got an answer accepted about 7 years after it was made...

Answer (score 0):

For react users, there's a react hook that uses google translate to translate a webpage easily in a clean manner.

It keeps your webpage looking clean without the clutter of google translate's widgets, and it's very customizable.

Install the hook library with
**npm install use-google-translate**

Example usage

```
import useGoogleTranslate from 'use-google-translate';


export default function Example() {

    const supportedLanguages = {
        en: {
            code: "en",//Required
            name: "English",//Optional
            isRTL: false,//Optional
            countryCode: "us"//Optional
        },
        "zh-CN": {
            code: "zh-CN",
            name: "中文",
            isRTL: false,
            countryCode: "cn"
        },
        ar: {
            code: "ar",
            name: "العربية",
            isRTL: true,
            countryCode: "sa"
        }
    }

    const futureTexts = [
        'This is an alert text that shows after clicking "Show Alert 1", and has been translated in the past for this time.',
        {
            id: 'show-alert-2', text: 'The is another alert text that shows after clicking "Show Alert 2", and has been translated in the past for this time.'
        }
    ]
    const mustTranslate = true

    const {
    lang,//current preferred, detected, or default language
    langs,//supportedLanguages
    isRTL,
    detectedCountryCode,
    supportsLanguage,
    getLanguageData,
    getTranslationFutureText,
    translate,
    translating,
    } = useGoogleTranslate(
        supportedLanguages, // *Required. The languages the translator should support

        "en", // *Required. The default language. This is also the language of the page

        // A text in the default language that the hook will add and hide as a div element to the page to detect when translation 
        // is done, by comparing the text content of this div on an interval of 200ms to this text.
        "Hello world", // *Required.

        // This are texts that will be displayed later. Such as in alert pop ups. 
        // The texts are added and hidden with unique ids as div elements to the page 
        // This allows the texts that will be needed in the lifespan of the page to be translated all at once, 
        // while the contents of these divs are returned with a simple function(getTranslationFutureText) when needed; 
        // to avoid layout change during user interactions that would cause another google translation process.
        futureTexts, 

        // If set to true, the page will reload when the translation has timed out without any translation done.
        // IF false, the translating state of will be set to false with no translation done.
        mustTranslate, // the default is true

        6000, // The translation process timeout in milliseconds. The default is 5000. That is, 5 seconds.
    );

    const handleAlert1 = () => {
        alert(getTranslationFutureText('This is an alert text that shows after clicking "Show Alert 1", and has been translated in the past for this time.'))
    }

    const handleAlert2 = () => {
        alert(getTranslationFutureText('show-alert-2'))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{display: translating? "none" : "block"}}>
                <h1>This is a test content for translation.</h1>
                <div>Current language: {lang}</div>
                <select onChange={(e) => {
                    translate(e.value)
                }}>
                {Object.keys(langs || {}).map((lng) => {
                    if (lng === lang) return null;
                    return (
                        <option key={index} value={lang.code}>{lang.name}</option>
                    )
                })}
                </select>
                <button onClick={handleAlert1}>Show Alert 1</button><br />
                <button onClick={handleAlert2}>Show Alert 2</button>
            </div>
            <div style={{display: !translating? "none" : "block", fontStyle: "italic"}}>...</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```