# Automatic translation of a webpage using google website translator

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I added translate to another language widget in my website.
Users can select the language from a dropdown menu.

Suppose, I know from which country my visitor is coming. Is there any way that I can always automatically trigger google website translator in that language?

Or I will make a beautiful landing page asking which language visitor wants to see and depending on that I will send them to translated webpage?

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but automatically providing a machine-translated page is a *really bad idea*. Reading machine translation can be really jarring. It's great if you want to get the gist of a blog post or something, but it's not something you'd want to interact with by default. Even if you provide a landing page it's a good idea to make it clear that it's a Google translation, otherwise it'll just make it look like you hired some really lousy translators.

Comment: it's a bad idea to use location because some countries have multiple official languages, eg Belgium, South Africa, Canada etc. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823022/detect-users-preferred-language-and-google-translate-automatically

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh - solution just posted using google translate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32020855/4258817, which shows the language-picker drop-down box only for non-English users (it's designed for a page in English). Just change the `en` (in two places) for whatever language the page is in.  Other solutions are to use a set of flags to represent languages, the user clicks the one they want and it translates. The google website translater will write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://<URL>#googtrans(1|2)
```

whrer 1 is the language code of the original webpage language and 2 is the language code to which google will translate.

example:

```
http://<your website url>#googtrans(en|es)
```

will translate to Spanish automatically.

Comment: From where came this function googtrans() ? Are you including any js file?

Comment: [Google Website Translator](https://translate.google.com/intl/en/about/website/) is no longer providing new access. Yes. Developers used to add some javascripts for the Google translation to work.