# Google Translate - Automatically detect browser language and translate from English

Tags: google-translate, detect

I have a site in English that I want to  automatically translate using google translate into other languages based on navigator language of the user's browser, i.e if their browser is in German - translate from English to German, if browser language is French, English to French etc.

I don't want the user to have to select language translation from a drop-down, but just have it translated according to their preferred browser language settings.

I've looked at every previous question and no-one seems to have sorted this. Can anyone help?

Thanks
Baz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect User's Preferred Language and Google Translate Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823022/detect-users-preferred-language-and-google-translate-automatically)