# internationalization on web pages

Tags: php, html, internationalization

What is the standard practice to support multiple languages within a domain?

In C++ we would create a resource file divided into sections for each language then depending on the users local we would load that section and apply any pre-translated text to menus etc.

Is there something similar available for HTML via PHP?

Is it possible to have an xml file containing a default element and further language specific elements containing the common text found on a website? Does such a 'database' already exist in the public domain?

I would like my site to first detect the users country and have an optional 'language' button available. Then text such as "Login" "Home" "About us" would be inserted into the HTML.

Please note, I do not wish to google translate.

Comment: Be sure to look for the browser's language settings before trying to determine the country by network or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a feature that makes localization easier, gettext.
[Here](http://phpmaster.com/localizing-php-applications-1/) you will find a decent tutorial about it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very broad question, but here's a short answer and some links for your further study:

- Detecting user preferred language is normally done using various factors including [GeoIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126959/how-to-find-the-geoip-location-for-all-users/9143618#9143618) and [OS and browser language settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823022/detect-users-preferred-language-and-google-translate-automatically/15961364#15961364).
- As was mentioned in other answers, using `gettext` in PHP is one common solution, but the format it uses to store the translated content is not XML. It's PO files which look like this:

  ```
   msgid "Enter a comma separated list of user names."
   msgstr "Eine kommagetrennte Liste von Benutzernamen."

   msgid "Goodbye!"
   msgstr "Aufwiedersehen!"
  ```
- PO files are formatted as MO file to be used by `gettext`:

  `msgfmt -o myPHPApp.mo myPHPApp.po`.
- These translation files are put under a directory structure like:

  `./locale/xx_XX/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`.
- Then you need to add this file to your PHP Code:

  ```
  <?php

  // Set language to German
  putenv('LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8');
  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8');

  // Specify location of translation tables
  bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");

  // Choose domain
  textdomain("myPHPApp");

  // Translation is looking for in ./locale/de_DE.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/myPHPApp.mo now

  // Print a test message
  echo gettext("Welcome to My PHP Application");

  // Or use the alias _() for gettext()
  echo _("Goodbye!");

  ?>
  ```

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid but that `setlocale()` is confusing me. Once set would it be applied system wide or is it required every time a new language is seen? What I mean is, is the language detection and setting of locale required each time a page is clicked?

Comment: Actually, it's a very good question hence it changes `LC_ALL` which is an environment variable. [`setLocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) is limited to the current script and [`putenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) "adds setting to the server environment [which] will only exist for the duration of the current request". 

Once the language is either detected or selected by the user, it's possible to store and identifier in the `$_SESSION` (like `$_SESSION['locale'])` so the language selection remains while the user navigates from one page to the other.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. As it happens, `Wordpress` on which I'm building my site, already has this support built in. Now, I must learn how to use it. I want to correctly format the strings as I go rather than going back to do it later.

Answer (score 0):

Most common is [PO](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) format. You can use [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php).

Regards!